# Set the position of UL to fixed, the dropdown does not work

Tags: html, css, navigation, hover

When I set the position of my UL to fixed then the drop list does not come when I hover on GAMES! But when I remove position fixed then drop down works, but the position of my entire UL changes

When I keep it fixed then it is stickied to top and left of screen like a navigation bar and this is what I want but when I remove position fixed the drop down works but it is no longer stickied to left and top and I tried setting margins but still it is not sticking to top and left! Here is my code:

HTML code :-

```
<ul>
<li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#news">Contact</a></li>
<li class="dropdown"><a href="#contact" class="dropbtn">Games</a>
 <div class="dropdown-content">
  <a href="#">PUBG</a>
  <a href="#">Fortnite</a>
  <a href="#">PUBG Mobile</a>
</div>
</li>
<li style="float:right"><a href="#about">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS code :-

```
ul {
list-style-type: none;
padding: 0;
overflow: hidden;
background-color: #333;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
margin-top: 0px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
}

li {
float: left;
}

li a, .dropbtn {
display: block;
color: white;
text-align: center;
padding: 14px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
background-color: #111;
text-decoration: none;
color: white;
}



li.dropdown {
display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
display: none;
background-color: #f9f9f9;
min-width: 160px;
box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
z-index: 1;
position: absolute;
}

.dropdown-content a {
color: black;
padding: 12px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #333}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
display: block;
}

.active {
background-color: #80e5ff;
color: black;
text-decoration: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
overflow: hidden;
```

Please remove above css in your `ul` css.

please run code snippet and see. It's working as per your expectation.

```css
ul {
list-style-type: none;
padding: 0;
background-color: #333;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
margin-top: 0px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
position:fixed;
}

li {
float: left;
}

li a, .dropbtn {
display: block;
color: white;
text-align: center;
padding: 14px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
background-color: #111;
text-decoration: none;
color: white;
}



li.dropdown {
display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
display: none;
background-color: #f9f9f9;
min-width: 160px;
box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
z-index: 1;
position: absolute;
}

.dropdown-content a {
color: black;
padding: 12px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #333}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
display: block;
}

.active {
background-color: #80e5ff;
color: black;
text-decoration: none !important;
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#news">Contact</a></li>
<li class="dropdown"><a href="#contact" class="dropbtn">Games</a>
 <div class="dropdown-content">
  <a href="#">PUBG</a>
  <a href="#">Fortnite</a>
  <a href="#">PUBG Mobile</a>
</div>
</li>
<li style="float:right"><a href="#about">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: you also add position:fixed in ul

Comment: can you share your code with me?. so I will help you to fix this bug.

Comment: u have done overflow: visible and position: fixed?

btw thnx a lot it worked :)

Comment: your most welcome. you are using *{ overflow: hidden; }. this css applicable in all element. if this css you don't want. please remove it otherwise you stuck every time.

Answer (score 0):

When you use position: fixed or position: absolute, those properties remove your tag from the flow of your document. If you are relying on the size of a tag that you try to position with one of those values, you are going to have problems.

Additionally, position: fixed may not be what you want, since a fixed position element is going to stay fixed relative to the viewport. You should try position: absolute instead. That will still remove that element from the flow of the document, but it will position it based on the next relative positioned parent element.

Comment: i positioned my UL to absolute, now my bar is sticked to top and left but now when i hover on Games then drop-list does not come out :(

i also removed overflow: hidden